# How does OWA keep me signed in even after cleaning my cookies?

Tags: windows-authentication, spnego, outlook-web-app

The internet is littered with forum posts asking how to sign out of OWA properly.  As a web developer, when I clear cookies and refresh and see that I'm still signed in, I get concerned.  I believe my company uses SPNEGO for OWA authentication, so I presume there is something there that keeps a session alive, but I want to understand how it works.

The currnet workflow I'm using is:

- Sign out of OWA (i'm told to close "all browser windows" but ...  no)
- clear all cookies for my domain
- point the browser to /owa
- after the first GET which sends no cookies, the server responds with a Set-Cookie with my old session ID.

If someone could explain this dark magic I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure your browser isn't just automatically reauthenticating with your windows credentials? (I don't really know how spnego works...)

Comment: yea i think thats exactly what is happening (thats what spnego is i think).  But why dont i see anything going between my browser and the server in the Network panel of firebug?)

Comment: If it IS Windows Auth it will be doing a challenge/response that returns a 401, which the browser will respond to. Could it be redirecting after that so your network tab gets cleared?